# Why can I create a vector of std::array?

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdarray

I thought that you should always determine what the size of an array is at compile time. I thought this was the case because a specific amount of memory would be allocated for that array.

Then, why is this not a problem:

```
std::vector<std::array<int,3>> something;
something.push_back(std::array<int,3> {1,2,3});
```

In this case you hace determined what the size of your array is, but you don't know how many that would be. At runtime you will be creating an unknown amount of arrays, so why is it possible to create arrays without knowing their memory allocation before hand?

Comment: `std::vector` is dynamically sized and always has been. There is no reason why making a vector of fixed-size arrays wouldn't be allowed

Comment: Why is it possible to create a vector of `int`s? You need to know how big an `int` is at compile time to allocate space for it. But at runtime you'd be creating an unknown amount of `int`s?

Comment: Why would that be a problem?  The size is specified at compile time.

Comment: That's the point of `std::vector` - it's not an array, but a resizable container (which is pretty much like an array for most uses). Are you asking how `std::vector` is able to achieve that?

Comment: The relevant search terms to learn more on this subject would be "automatic allocation" versus "dynamic allocation". Some references will call this "stack" and "heap" allocation, but those are implementation details, and a standard compliant compiler does not need to use either of those data structures (although many do).

Comment: Would you be equally surprised if the type was `mystery_type<int, 3>` and you had no idea what it was supposed to represent?

Comment: Maybe you're overthinking this.  What you have is a `std::vector<T>`.  That `T` in your case is `std::array<int,3>`.  As long as `T` has the proper requirements to be placed in a `std::vector`, there is nothing strange.  You could even have a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` or even `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>`

Comment: None of your `std::array<int, 3>` objects are changing size. You are just making more of them.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it, it that wouldnt work, then `std::vector<int>` would not work for the same reason. You do not need to know the number of elements in a `std::vector` beforehand, because the vector manages dynamically the memory needed to store the elements.

The `std::array<int,3>`s are always the same size, and thats what the vector needs to know to allocate memory for them.

Moreover, `sizeof( std::vector<T> )` is a constant. It does not change when you push more elements, just as the `sizeof` this

```
 struct foo {
     int * p;
 };
```

is always the same, no matter whether `p` points to an array with `1` or `42` elements.